Check convergence of a trigonometric series
I have a problem with the following series:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \tan \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$
My idea is to check if it's absolutely convergent.
As $x\to 0$ we can use following inequalities $\frac{x}{2}<\sin x<x$ and $x<\tan x<2x$. So for following series:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\sin \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \tan \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}|$$
We have $$\frac{1}{2n}<|\sin \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \tan \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}|<\frac{2}{n}$$
Using Comaprison test we can conclude that $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\sin \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \tan \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}|$ is divergent. Unfortunately, it doesn't help me with answering the main question.
I would really appreciate your help and hints.
Best, K

Your estimates also show that all factors are positive and therefore the absolute values do not make a difference.

@SeverinSchraven you're right, I've totally missed the fact that both sin and tan for x in (0,1] are positive. Therefore I don't need to use absolute values. I can simply drop absulute values in last inequlaity, and by using comparison test simply conlcude that the main series is divergent. Thanks a lot!

That's a series of numbers greater than $0$, and so the comparison test can be used. You have\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt n}\right)\tan\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt n}\right)}{\dfrac1n}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt n}\right)}{\dfrac1{\sqrt n}}\cdot\dfrac{\tan\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt n}\right)}{\dfrac1{\sqrt n}}\\&=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt n}\right)}{\dfrac1{\sqrt n}}\right)\cdot\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\tan\left(\dfrac1{\sqrt n}\right)}{\dfrac1{\sqrt n}}\right)\\&=1.\end{align}So, since since the harmonic series diverges, your series diverges.

Thanks, my mistake was to go for absolute divergence without checking whether this is really necessary.

For your curiosity.
If $$a_n=\sin \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right) \tan \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$$ by Taylor
$$a_n=\color{red}{\frac{1}{n}}+\frac{1}{6 n^2}+\frac{31}{360 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ Using generalized harmonic numbers
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^p a_n=H_p+\frac{1}{6}H_p^{(2)}+\frac{31}{360} H_p^{(3)}+\cdots$$
Using the asymptotics
$$S_p= \left(\gamma +\frac{\pi
   ^2}{36}+\frac{31 }{360}\zeta (3)\right)+\log (p)+\frac{1}{3 p}-\frac{31}{720 p^2}+\frac{11}{720
   p^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right)$$

Observe that for large enough $n$, $a_n \ge \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}= \dfrac{1}{2n}$. Since $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{2n}$ diverges, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty  a_n$ diverges by the comparison test.
